# Почему выдаёт ошибку Uncaught ReferenceError: clicked is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick?

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь скрыть определённый блок и добавить классы к другому блоку, но почему-то выдаёт ошибку. Уже кучу способов перепробовал, но всегда одно и то же.
Вот код html:

```
<div class="header_offer_wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="header_offer">
    <p>Подарочные сертификаты <span></span></p>
  </a>
  <button class="header_offer_close_wrapper" onclick="clicked()">
    <span class="header_offer_close">+</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

код javascript

```
if(localStorage.getItem("vivsible") === "false") {
  const rec = document.querySelector(".header_offer_wrapper")
  rec.style.display = "none"
  const blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".header")
  for (let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++ ) {
    blocks[i].classList.add("someclass")
  }
}

const clicked = () => {
  const rec = document.querySelector(".header_offer_wrapper")
  rec.style.display = "none"
  const blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".header")
  for (let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++ ){
    blocks[i].classList.add("someclass")
  }

  localStorage.setItem("vivsible", "false")
}
```

Comment: потому что код js находится ниже вызова этой самой функции

Comment: Что предлагаете поменять? По идеи оно должно работать, как стоит

Comment: Вы предлагаете обернуть весь, код который я скинул в function clicked(){ весь код } ? Если да, то оно вообще перестало работать и вызывать ошибку

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/function-expressions#function-expression-v-sravnenii-s-function-declaration

Comment: @keit265 зачем же весь код

Comment: "По идеи оно должно работать, как стоит"  --- но ведь не работает......именно поэтому вы здесь

Comment: вместо const сделать let........ либо код js перенести вверх......., либо перенести в файл и подключить сверху............ либо вместо инлайн вызова использовать addEventListener и ссылку на функцию.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский попробовал всё, до сих пор не работает и выдаёт ошибку

Comment: На слово я не верю

Comment: и как я покажу...

Comment: Очевидно в вопрос добавить разные варианты попыток

Comment: @АлексейШиманский зачем мне тебя обманывать?... Мне нужно решить проблему, для чего мне писать, что не работает

Comment: Нужно посмотреть в код, чтобы сказать что ты делаешь не так. вот и всё

Comment: Я решил проблему тем, что переместил скрипт в файлик с php вне(выше) html, он стал убирать блок и добавлять нужные классы, но почему-то не запоминает, что я уже нажимал на крестик и после перезагрузки слетает. Может быть где-то ошибка в скрипте?